# send UTF16 chars to server side without encoding/ without increasing the size?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, utf-8, utf-16

Consider I have UTF 16 chars as like this:  Ả㠵堥  in million. 
I am sending this through ajax call as follow: 
Js side:

```
var compressed = LZString.compressToUTF16(uncompressed64Data);
    jQuery.ajax({
data :"img=+" compressed 
}
```

Java side:

```
String utf16values = request.getParameter("img");
```

Is anyway I can able to get the UTF16 chars as it is in server side without encoding/ without increasing the size?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Like in your previous question, you're really asking the wrong question. This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You don't want to send `UTF16` to the server. You want to send image data to the server. Use `POST` and send unencoded (i.e. remove the base64 encoding first) binary data. This approach is just ridiculous, not to mention wasteful.

Comment: @Kayaman : the image data as base64 format provided by third party which I cant control. So I am doing my best to bring down the size. Prev question is one way of try out and I am still pursuing it.. I believe development is a part of try outs and I am doing as much way I can. Hope this is not waste!!

Comment: You don't need to control the third party. If you have image data in base64 encoded form, you can decode it and send the data as a binary stream with `POST`, using a lot less bandwidth than with what you're trying to invent here. All that UTF8/UTF16/Base64 stuff is just useless, and you're making this a lot harder problem than what it really is. Development isn't just trying and failing, you're allowed to use your brains too.

Comment: You want to set binary data (image) to server. Don't try to send it as text! Send it as bytes! You'll get the smallest bandwidth! You won't have to hack around with encodings! It'll be easier! It'll be better!

Comment: HTTP request and response bodies are always binary data, though there must be an agreement on how to interpret the bytes, possibly expressed through a header. You might as well make the body be the binary data that you want, rather than some misapplication of character encodings.

Comment: Also please don't use non-english words like "in lacs". There's going to be a lot of people who have no idea what you mean

Comment: @JamesZ Does "in lacs" translate to the idiom "in spades"?

Comment: @TomBlodget I assume it literally means several hundred thousand, but probably just a large amount or something like that.

Comment: @Kayaman : I can able to send it as image stream,. Thanks for your enlightment :) . Please post that as answer, I will accept as answer.

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer, that'll be clearer to anyone who comes across this question.